# Iterating over unknown keys in php array (created with array_count_values)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I have an array like this -

`$fruit = Array ( [0] => bananas [1] => apples [2] => apples [3] => oranges [4] => oranges [5] => apples )`

With which I have created a new array using `array_count_values` to count the individual fruits.

`$fruitSorted = array_count_values($fruit)`

Which looks like this:

```
Array ( [bananas] => 1 [oranges] => 2 [apples] => 3
```

So far I am happy. But I would like to iterate over the second array, but without knowing the names of the keys.
Should it instead be a multi-dimensional array? I am not sure how to directly convert it.
More directly, I would like to

```
foreach ($fruitSorted as $a){
    echo $a." is the value";
    //how to I select the key instead without knowing its name?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$key => $value` in the [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach ($fruitSorted as $key => $value){
   echo $key . " is the key, and " . $value . " is the value" ;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I did not realise you could do that, so simple!